# "No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I found some answer for this question, that I should change compileSdkVersion 26 buildToolVersion "26.0.1"

This worked but I don't want to change my compileSdkVersion, because that causes many problems in my app like notification not working and my install app receiver is not working too.

Before updating Android Studio it was working fine, but now it gives me error.

```
 buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
repositories {
jcenter() // includes the MoPub SDK and AVID library
maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }

}

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.frizza"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 29
    versionName "3.8"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-crashlytics.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-square-retrofit.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-square-picasso.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-square-okhttp.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-support-v7-appcompat.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-google-play-services.pro'
    }

}
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude '.readme'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':SlidingMenu')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
//    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'

compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2"

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

compile files('libs/assl_sdk_rmn.jar')

//// For interstitials 
//    compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-interstitial:4.16.1@aar') {
//        transitive = true 
//    }
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: i am sorry that i had written urgent, but i need help cause i had to release my app to playstore for the feature that i am working for last week, but could not release due to this error, please help me out

Comment: (It's worth noting that people who edit and comment are not necessarily folks who can help, but either way, please do not try to justify begging here - we don't like it, full stop. We get a lot of people adding "please help me" to _all_ of their comments too, and we'd rather people didn't do that for the same reason. People may help you, and if they do, it will be at their leisure `:-)`. Good luck with your question).

Comment: setKeyboardNavigationCluster was added in API 26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's look like `setKeyboardNavigationCluster` was added in [API 26](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setKeyboardNavigationCluster(boolean)) for `View`, or support library [v26.0.1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setKeyboardNavigationCluster(android.view.View,%20boolean)).

For both cases you need to update `compileSdkVersion` to API 26.